# Underbars in symbol names when linking against an external library

Tags: c, xcode, static-linking, mex

I'm trying to compile a C library and then some external C code liked against it and I'm having issues with my external code finding the symbols within the library. I don't understand  the big flick and am hoping someone can help. Here are the details:

1) I'm working on a Mac. I've compiled the library as a static .a library in xcode.

2) I'm attempting to compile external code calling functions from the library. I've included the header file and I'm specifying it's location and the library in the gcc call. The compilation seems to complete ok, but the linking fails stating that symbols cannot be found.

3) The missing symbols are listed as _FunctionName where FunctionName is the name of the function I called.

It is not clear to me why the compiler/linker has added underbars to my function names. But my naive guess is that is why the symbols can not be found in the library.

The external code compilation is being done through MATLAB's mex() function which is making the gcc calls below in the background.

I'd be thankful for any thoughts anyone might have.

```
gcc-4.2 -c  -Igsf_0303/ -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/extern/include \
-DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -fno-common -no-cpp-precomp -arch x86_64 -isysroot \
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5  -fexceptions  \
-DMX_COMPAT_32 -O2 -DNDEBUG  "gsf_tester.c"

gcc-4.2 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl, \
-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,\
-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map \
-o  "gsf_tester.mexmaci64"  gsf_tester.o  gsf_0303/libgsf.a \
-L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011b.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++

Undefined symbols:
  "_gsfOpen", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in gsf_tester.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mex: link of ' "gsf_tester.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

Comment: What names do your symbols have in your library? (run `nm -g library.a` to list all exported symbols in the file library.a)

Comment: Prepending an underscore is a common way for the compiler to name C functions when compiled. As you can see in the error message `mexFunction` also have it. Are you sure the file containing `gfsOpen` really is added to the library?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess.  Firstly, Joachim's comment is correct.  C function names will always be prepended with an underscore.  So that's not the issue.

So either `gfsOpen()` is missing from the library or it's not visible or it can't be seen when `gfs_tester.o` is linked.

So check that gfsOpen is in the library.  This should do it

```
otool -t -v sgsf_0303/libgsf.a | grep gsfOpen
```

The above disassembles the file and then greps the symbol you are interested in from it.  There's probably a better way, but I haven't bothered to research it.

Check it's not declared `static`.

Make sure the architecture of the library matches (`otool -fv`)

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. Using the tools you suggested I found that, indeed gsfOpen was not in the symbol table. This lead to some further investigation into what I actually compiled into my library. I'd created another bit of code to test the library and it was included in the file list for the project when I compiled the library inadvertently. After removing this and recompiling I was able to compile and run my function in MATLAB without error. I don't understand the details of my stupidness, but I'm thankful that its working and more thankful for your help.

Comment: @user2932: you should probably create an answer to your own question with the text of your comment and accept it.  That way, anybody coming here looking for an answer to the same problem will find your solution more easily.